# Filtering a django Prefetch based on more fields from the root object

Tags: django, django-models

This is similar to other questions regarding complicated prefetches but seems to be slightly different. Here are some example models:

```py
class Author(Model):
    pass

class Book(Model):
    authors = ManyToManyField(Author, through='BookAuthor')

class BookAuthor(Model):
    book = ForeignKey(Book, ...)
    author = ForeignKey(Author, ...)

class Event(Model):
    book = ForeignKey(Book, ...)
    author = ForeignKey(Author, ...)
```

In summary: a `BookAuthor` links a book to one of its authors, and an `Event` also concerns a book and one of its authors (the latter constraint is unimportant). One could design the relationships differently but it's too late for that now, and in my case, this in fact is part of migrating away from the current setup.

Now suppose I have a `BookAuthor` instance and want to find any events that relate to that combination of book and author. I can follow either the `book` *or* `author` relations on `BookAuthor` and their `event_set` reverse relationship, but neither gives me what I want and, if I have several `BookAuthor`s it becomes a pain.

It seems that the way to get an entire queryset "annotated" onto a model instance is via `prefetch_related` but as far as I can tell there is no way, in the `Prefetch` object's `queryset` property, to refer to the root object's fields. I would like to do something like this:

```py
BookAuthor.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'book__event_set',
        queryset=Event.objects.filter(
            author=OuterRef('author')
        )
    }    
)
```

However, `OuterRef` only works in subqueries and this is not one. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461476/prefetch-related-with-a-filter-that-contains-a-field-of-the-original-model) suggests I could use a subquery here but I don't understand how it could ever work: you have to put the subquery inside a query to work in the `Prefetch`, and the `OuterRef` refers to *that* object/DB row; there is no way to get back to the original, root object. If I translate the code there into my situation it is clear that the `OuterRef` is referring to the outer `Event` query, not the outer `BookAuthor`.

To make the question precise: what I want is O(1) queries which, for a queryset of `BookAuthors` annotate each instance - or one of its foreign keys - with a collection of the corresponding `Event`s. Obviously one can get all the `Events` and glue everything together in python. I want to avoid this but if anyone has a particularly elegant way of doing that, it would also be useful to know.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I did not find an exact answer to this question, however I found this blogpost: https://devblog.kogan.com/blog/custom-relationships-in-django and this repository: https://github.com/alexhill/django-relativity which allowed me to solve my problem.

Comment: Thank's I'll look into them.